# How do I change the Blend Node to Vertical?

Tags: python, node-editor

In my script I have added a Blend Node (in the texture editor) and I would like to define the direction of the gradient.

`blend = tex_tree.nodes.new('TextureNodeTexBlend')
 blend.location = (0,100)
 blend.use_flip_axis = 'VERTICAL'`

I thought adding the `.use_flip_axis = 'VERTICAL'` would work but it says it has no attribute use_flip_axis

What am I missing?..

Comment: I guess the API isn't finished yet or this is a bug @Darkfall You can test it using the *Console* and you will see that there neither is `progression` nor `use_flip_axis` available. But it should, according to the API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendTexture.html?highlight=use_flip_axis#bpy.types.BlendTexture.use_flip_axis E.g. all properties for the *Output Node* are available.

Comment: @brockmann, so should I report as a bug and hope they fix it?. In the mean time, could I use a rotation right after the Blend node?. It seems the rotate node is different in the texture editor than in the compositor.. It has a value for "Turns" not degrees..  I am not sure how to use it properly..

Comment: I didn’t test ,but looks like it’s a property of the texture and not the node. See if tex_tree.use_flip_axis does it.

Comment: @AFWS I tried and gave the same message,,

Comment: You need an object of type `BlendTexture` to set `use_flip_axis`, however the node is of type `TextureNodeTexBlend`. Seems to me that brockmann may be right and the API hasn't been properly updated for this node. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendTexture.html https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.TextureNodeTexBlend.html

Comment: @rjg so the code I wrote should work but it hasn't yet been updated?.. That being so, for a work around how can I use the Rotate Node in the Texture editor? It seems like everything I try does nothing.. it has a value for Turns not rotation..

Comment: @Darkfall yes and no. An instance of the node should of course provide access to all settings, but currently that's not the case for the Python API. Yes you can use the *Rotate* node. The *Turns* parameter is part of the inputs and can be set like this, for example `bpy.data.textures['Texture'].node_tree.nodes["Rotate"].inputs["Turns"].default_value = 0.5`

Comment: @rjg ok thanks for the Information! and thanks to all of you guys taking the time!!..

Comment: I'd report as bug. Doesn't seem to work in 2.79 either ,but it should. Works if not using nodes ```bpy.data.textures["Texture"].use_flip_axis = 'VERTICAL'``` ,but not this ```bpy.data.textures["Texture"].node_tree.use_flip_axis = 'VERTICAL'```